# What does “snug as a nun’s wimple or loose as a suggestion mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The Time Magazine’s article (November 5, 2015) titled, “Is Iran finally ready for change?” begins with the following passage:

> “The politics of Iran may be relentlessly convoluted, but for years it
>   was possible to judge at least the general direction of things by
>   doing a little girl watching. Or, at least, trying to. Hijab that can
>   be worn snug as a nun’s wimple or **loose as a suggestion** – was of
>   immense importance to Iranian hard-liners, who like Romantic poets and
>   Miss Clairol equated hair with sexuality, a quality strictly forbidden
>   in public."

I cannot get an idea of the meaning and analogy of ‘(Hijab) worn snug as a nun’s wimple or “loose as a suggestion.”’ What does it mean? Is “loose as a suggestion” a popular set of words?

Comment: The unfortunateness of the phrase 'by doing a little girl watching' is absolutely astounding on a staggering scale.  I'm flummoxed at how it ever passed Time's editors to actually make it into publication.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Why, what is wrong with it? Aside from a possible lost hyphen it seems to adequately covey the author's meaning that observing the current female fashion in Iran is a suitable barometer to the religious politics in play...

Comment: @Benjamin Hamrman. I suspect you were flummoxed beause you read the quote 'by doing a little-girl wattching.'. But if you read it as 'by doing a little (while) a  girl-watching,'.are you still angry? I'm asking this because  mere girl watching by young men doesn't seem so  unusual and loose behavior to me. May be I'm reading wrong.

Comment: @Marv Mills : The phrase "by doing a little girl watching" creates a double-entendre whose other meaning couches pedophilia, and it doesn't appear accidental.  The entire paragraph is steeped in sexual innuendo. Snug as a nun's wimple?  Loose as a suggestion?  Please.

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi : I'm not angry.  Flummoxed doesn't mean angry.  I'm surprised and bewildered by the comment.  The first sentence can be taken to mean that one can surmise the situation by having sex with a little girl, one who is watching nearby.  This other meaning might be able to be overlooked as an unfortunate choice of words, were it not for several other sexual innuendos being made in the same breath.  To say that it is all accidental stretches probability and credibility, and it  chooses to ignore allusions the author clearly intended, for words are what he does.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I haven't read the rest of the article, but I don't see it myself. You know a "wimple" is a nun's bonnet right? You have heard the song "Music to Watch Girls By", right? YMMV, of course, but I don't see it as "steeped in sexual innuendo" at all, if I had to judge its innuendo out of ten, I'd give it one.

Comment: Of course there's some sexual innuendo, that's the point of the paragraph (judge the state of politics by how much sexuality is repressed). But it's extremely farfetched to read _pedophilia_ in that, that would not even be grammatical and that meaning would make no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example sentence, the right clip should be as follows:

> Hijab that can be worn **snug as a nun’s wimple** / or **loose as a
>   suggestion**...

The bold parts are being contrasted. *Loose as a suggestion* is not an idiom or popular set of words.

[Suggestion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/suggestion) means:

> A slight indication of something

[Snug](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/snug) means:

> Very tight or close-fitting

The adjective *loose* is an antonym of *snug*.

So your example could be rephrased to:

> Hijab (which was not allowed to be worn loosely in the past) can be worn (either)
>   very tightly like a nun’s wimple or loosely as a suggestion of
>   change (from the past in terms of sexuality, attitude, and way of thinking) of a woman...

Now it is allowed for Iranian women to wear Hijab more loosely than before to express their attitude or way of thinking towards sexuality.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not a popular set of words. *Loose as a suggestion* is a  [simile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simile) apparently devised by the author of that article (judging by the fact that all Google hits for that collocation point right to it).

Apparently the author perceives (many) suggestions as inherently *loose* (reading *vague* perhaps), which grounds the simile here. Another reading, bordering on guesswork of course, may be *loose as a suggestion of a Hijab*, meaning that the wearer can express herself by adjusting her Hijab loosely rather than tightly.